# pydev massive cpu usage

Tags: python, aptana, pydev

I am using pydev through Aptana Studio 3 on a mac.  Shortly after opening up Aptana, my computer heats way up, the fans go full power, and Aptana uses over 100% cpu even when it's not doing anything.  I also have pydev on eclipse, but this spike doesn't occur.  Has anyone else seen this? Is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to really know what's going on would be connecting jvisualvm (or some profiler or debugger) to your process to see what's going on (and then report an issue). On jvisualvm you can get a dump with the current processes, which may be enough already if you can say which is the thread that's running.

Note that the title should probably be 'aptana studio 3 massive cpu usage' if you're able to reproduce it there but not in pydev...